# Why still chrony is not taking time from PPS after 197 hours?

Tags: linux, chrony, gpsd

I'm using chrony where GPSD and the PPS will be used for accurate timings. my chrony.conf file as follows,

```
refclock SHM 0 delay 0.8 refid NMEA trust prefer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
allow all                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
refclock PPS /dev/pps1 refid PPS poll 4 trust prefer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
rtcsync                                                                                                                                                 
logchange 0.5                                                                                                                                           
local stratum 10                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                        
logdir /var/log/chrony                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                        
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys                                                                                                                         
commandkey 10                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                        
dumpdir /var/log/chrony
```

After configuring the conf file I kept running chrony for almost 196 hours. But still, the PPS are not used as a reference clock.

After using `chronyc sources` command I got the following response,

```
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
#x NMEA                          0   4   377     9    +87ms[  +87ms] +/-  401ms
#x PPS                           0   4   377    15    +44us[  +48us] +/-  419us
```

Is the chrony.conf file configuration is an issue here?
Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: @roaima okay got it next time I will keep it in mind. Can you please help me out here?

Comment: @OmkarDixit Pleas _remove_ the image from your post and instead replace it with the actual text that you want to show. The text is unreadable.

Comment: Which reference clock do you want the system to synchronise to? "A person with a watch knows what time it is. A person with two watches is never sure."

Comment: I want system to synchronise with pps and I'm expecting *at pps and + at gps. But I'm getting x at the both

Comment: According to examples in `chrony.conf(5)`man page, your `refclock PPS` line might need a `lock NMEA` refclock option to pair the pulse-per-second signal with the GPS reference clock, as the PPS signal by itself won't provide full time information.

Comment: Without more performance details we can only guess; maybe try [7.2.1 What should I know about various GPS Receivers?](https://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/ntp-s-refclk/#721-what-should-i-know-about-various-gps-receivers).